# Can't connect to Internet using WiFi

Tags: windows-7, networking

My Windows 7 computer won't connect to the Internet using WiFi. When I open Internet Explorer it can't find any pages - if I try to use the guide to solve the problem it says that the DNS server isn't responding. I have tried the following without any luck:

```
NETSH INT IP RESET
NETSH WINSOCK RESET
```

My Windows Vista computer connects to the Internet via WiFi without any issues. The only difference I can see is that when I run `ipconfig`, the Vista machine has a "Link-local IPv6 Address" but the Windows 7 machine doesn't.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

**UPDATE:** I believe this may be connected to DNS, because I can access Google via its IP: http://209.85.229.10

Comment: You could always try using the opendns name servers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS You might also consider turning off DNS relay if your router/WAP is using it. Though for the later you might need to reboot the router and then renew your DHCP lease (`ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`) to make sure the DNS server IPs get pushed down to the client you are working on. You can use `ipconfig /all` to check which DNS servers you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the OS

Answer (score 1):

You might try to disable IPv6. This is explained in detail in this article:

[How To Disable IPv6 In Windows 7](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably already did that, but try to update wifi drivers for you Win7 machine. It suddenly helped me month ago.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide suggestions when you do not provide info about what sort of network your Win 7 computer is attempting to operate in.

Some questions off the top of my head ...

1. How are your systems connected to the Internet? I am assuming you have a router/WAP and  either a DSL or cable modem. But it would help to know for sure and to know which make/model of router/WAP you are using.
2. How complicated is your LAN? How many systems and/or devices are connected to it?
3. Can you connect to your LAN router from the Win 7 computer using a **wired** ethernet connection?
4. Can you connect to your router from the Win 7 computer using **wireless**?
5. Is your router using any sort of local access filtering? For example, is it restricted to only allowing specific MAC addresses?
6. Is this possibly a DHCP problem? Perhaps the maximum number of allowed IP addresses already been assigned by the routers DHCP?

Could you post the info returned by running `ipconfig` with no other parameters on this Win 7 system?

---

> I belive its something to do with the dns since i can visit google by typing in the ip in the browser

So what is different between the DNS settings for the Vista laptop and the Win 7 laptop?

Does `ipconfig /all` show that both laptops are using the same DNS server IP addresses when connected via Wi-Fi? (I would also check what you get when you use wired ethernet to connect).

You could also try using `nslookup` in a command prompt on both to see what happens when you attempt to resolve `www.google.com`.

FWIW, here's a link to a MS Knowledge Base article: [Using NSlookup.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525)

Keep in mind that if it is a DNS problem one would expect it to show up on all the computers using the router since they all should be using the same DNS servers. This doesn't appear to be the case so something must be different.

My first guess is that something is wrong with the DNS servers assigned to the Win 7 laptop.

Unfortunately, I do not have a second guess at the moment.

Comment: 1) yes im using a router, and i belive that the router works fine since my vista machine connects both to the nerwork printer and the internet with no problem. My Win7 machine can only communcate with the networkprinter, not the internet.

2) Its pretty simple one router with build in wifi. 1 pc connected by cable(win xp) 1 laptop(vista) 1 laptop (win7)
3) Yes wired connection works fine, i can even connect to the internet using wired connection
4) Yes it connect to the router and i can use the network printer
5) No, and everything worked prefectly until yesterday
6) Dont think so

Comment: I belive its something with the dns to do, since i can visit google by typing in the ip in the browser